# How to reset zoom in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse

In Eclipse one can use <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>+</kbd> and <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>-</kbd> to zoom a text editor.

How can I reset the zoom level back to default(100%) ?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Text zooming is implemented in Eclipse, by changing the preference of the editor text size. There is no *Zoom 100%* command, but you can reset the text editor font (assuming you are using the default text editor font):

In ***Window > Preferences: General > Appearance > Colors and Fonts*** select ***Basic > Text Font*** and click ***Reset*** and ***Apply and Close***.

Comment: On a MAC you find Preferences on the "Eclipse" menu as expected.