# How do I undo zoom in in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, console

I use MacOS High Siearra. My Eclipse IDE version is Oxygen 3(4.3.2). I have a big problem.

I accidentally shrunk my console area and text in the text field (using <kbd>Command</kbd> <kbd>-</kbd> shortcut), and now when I turn the screen back on, I close my tabs and when I reopen them the page opens in the smallest size. I have to fix it every time.

Also, I have not been able to make my console screen larger again if using a mouse. I'm glad you helped me. I also thought about reinstalling the IDE, but when I delete it from the application screen and install it again, I still have the same problem. I think I could not delete it with all the system folders.

Please help me.
Thanks

Comment: Have you tried switching to a new workspace? I think these settings should be stored at workspace level.

Comment: Don't blame me for trying: Have you tried `Ctrl` + `+`?

Comment: try `command` + `+`

Comment: I tried it, but when I turn off the tap and reopen it, it reopens with the smallest state

Comment: I can not explain the problem completely, I guess I can enlarge it with command + +. I constantly have to enlarge the texts in the frames

Comment: You can try to set the text size by going to `Window -> Preferences -> General -> Appearance -> Colors and Fonts` and here you can reset or set new text font and color.

Comment: Vasan, Yes your solution make up. But my new question how do I move the old workspace to the new workspace??

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to reset zoom in Eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47506359/how-to-reset-zoom-in-eclipse)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These settings are stored in the workspace metadata which on mac is at location:

`<your root path>/eclipse-workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.runtime/.settings` . Remove the intended setting from there and restart eclipse.
For example, my editor settings are in the file `org.eclipse.ui.editors.prefs` with content:

`eclipse.preferences.version=1
lineNumberRuler=true
overviewRuler_migration=migrated_3.1
spellingEnabled=true`

Comment: Is there a way to delete the .metadata file directly? Do not you wipe it off, will it make a wound?

Comment: You can delete .metadata directory completely, it will get created when you restart eclipse. Although, it will remove all your settings. If you have already created a new workspace, you can copy things over from there.

Comment: yes, but all my project have disappeared from the project explorer, so I opened them all again with “file-> open project file system. I had a problem here, a few project were opened normally, but one was opened as a github repository. I didn’t solve it and my new apache tomcat gives me an error like it didn’t run continuously for 45 seconds